# How can I change Thunderbird's quoted text color?

Tags: email, thunderbird, css

I did this years ago and it was not hard, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out now how I changed the color of the "reply" quoted text when I reply.  I don't know if it was in a .css file or if I did it within Thunderbird, but I've changed it to a pale light green that was okay for a while but I've decided it's just too light for my needs, and want to change it to something darker.  Does anyone know the way to do this?  I think it's persisted through several updates of Thunderbird, too...so perhaps it's something I did locally in my profile?

To be clear, I'm talking about the text that's quoted after I click "Reply," the stuff someone else wrote, that's appearing below my message.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to true in [Config. editor](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor).

Then edit userContent.css (or [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css)) in your [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder).

You can get the CSS [from here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/ejg9h0/is_it_possible_to_use_css_to_change_quote_colours/) (remember to click the "continue this thread"-links to get more CSS so it works in both HTML and plain text messages.

Comment: This worked and is what I did in the past.  In going to the userChrome.css file I found a note where I'd changed it from the original.  THANK YOU.  I didn't look in the Chrome directory; otherwise, I think I would have found the file on my own.  But none of the files in the default profile folder were .css   Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to [install](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-addon-thunderbird) an addon.

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/quotecolors/?src=search
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/new-quotecolors/?src=search
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/quote-colors/?src=search

Note that not all addons work for all versions of Thunderbird.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I think in my case, I've (if I remember right) hard-coded it, meaning this may not work.  But I'll look into it.  Ideally, I'd also love to know the location of the file where this is set so I can adjust it back to defaults or such.  But again, thank you!

Comment: Ah, I just tried, and got a rather scary message that "Quote colors requires full access to Thunderbird, and your computer."  Not sure I'm willing to give a simple add-on that much permissions.  So I guess it's back to the location of that file.  I have a fairly vivid memory of it just being a matter of editing css somewhere.  Just can't remember where.

Comment: @confused I added another answer.